# How to get input value attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target value of the `value` attribute in the input field that immediately precedes the label with a `class="selected"`

```
<div id="placeholder">
<div id="product-options" class="options">

    <input checked="checked" id="option_33295465" name="cart[add][id]" type="radio" value="33295465" class="input_hidden"/>
    <label for="option_33295465" class="selected">
        <span>option1</span>
    </label>

    <input id="option_33544344" name="cart[add][id]" type="radio" value="33544344" class="input_hidden"/>
    <label for="option_33544344">
        <span>option2</span>
    </label>

</div>
</div>
```

At the moment I'm just trying to log the value, but I get undefined each time.

```
$('body').on('click','#button1',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $item = jQ('#placeholder').find('.selected').prev().attr('value');
    console.log($item); // Logs "undefined"
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/HybkH/)

Comment: Where's the element with id `placeholder` ?

Comment: Works fine here...http://jsfiddle.net/HybkH/4/

Comment: Apologies - question edited to accurately reflect actual DOM tree.

Comment: @verism Urm.. your code already works - http://jsfiddle.net/HybkH/3/

Comment: @Zenith - you're right, but somehow it wasn't functioning in my problem code. For some reason `.val()` did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a seperate method for retrieving the value of any form input: val()

```
$item = jQ('#placeholder').find('.selected').prev().val();
```

should do the trick, See also [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function on the element.

The other thing is that your jQuery code to get the option/radio button value can be simplified to:

```
$('#product-options input:checked').val()
```

Comment: or just `#product-options :checked`. Only `input` elements can be `:checked` after all ;)

Comment: That's good to know, but I'm not looking for the `checked` value in this particular instance.